# Why do nested UIStackViews with UILabels require Y position and height constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

I am trying to sort out a problem we have in a `UITableViewCell`. There are nested `UIStackView`s with subviews like `UILabel` having an intrinsic content size. I created this example for simplified explanation of my problem:

[image: screenshot of the example storyboard]

Results in these interface builder errors:

```
Top Stack 
View Need constraints for: Y position, height
Middle Stack 
View Need constraints for: Y position, height
Bottom Stack 
View Need constraints for: Y position, height
```

- To my (and my collegues) understanding, the stacks' and table view cell sizes should be determined by the `UILabel`s and their intrinsic content size.
- The "Outer Stack View" has four space constraints to its superview (the "Table View Cell") with 0 as constants because ultimately the table view cell and all stack view sizes should be based on the content views.
- All `UIStackView` have `Fill` for Alignment and Distribution attributes.
- I just dragged it together from the library as depicted, no fiddling in the inspector. It is simple to reproduce.
- Adding 0-space top and bottom constraints to a label in relation to its parent stack view does not resolve the stack view allegedly lacking a height constraint.
- The suggested constraints of the interface builder are nonsense.

What is missing? I created an [example project](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/NestedStackViewsExample) hosted on GitHub.

Comment: did you try with a greater than or equal to cero? from the outerStackView to the bottom of the cells contentView?

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the `OutterStackView` bottom constraint to be `greater than or equal` to the bottom of the cells content view.

[image]

[image]

See the issue is that you are asking the `OutterStackView` to be the same size as your cell in the StoryBoard but since your internal labels don't have their final intrinsic content size yet, you cannot fulfill all constraint requirements.

Comment: According to [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel), UILabel does have an intrinsic content size by default.

Comment: Sorry if i miss use the word, not native speaker, what i meant was that hour outterstack view wants to be a size that it cannot fulfill in the storyboard, only once you call cellForRow, the cell size is calculated correctly, not while in the storyboard

Comment: A constraint to connect the outer stack view bottom with the cell content view bottom did not solve the issues. Adding a `>= 22` constraint to a label resoves the missing constraint problem for its stack view above.

Comment: Yes it does, see my screenshot, i used the same layout.

Comment: I was also facing similar issue. For me adding >= constraints to bottom of outer UIStackView to superview solved the problem.

Comment: This solution also fixed the problem for me, but to get rid of the errors in IB I found I had to increase the height of the cell so that the bottom constraint was `> myPaddingValue`, i.e. basically drag the cell to be slightly bigger than it was.